# Torch-like permutation for arrays?

Tags: list-manipulation, tensors

Update: edited to clarify my confusion.

In Mathematica `Transpose[]` operates like this:

```
x = Table[i, {i, 1, 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5}];
x = ArrayReshape[x, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}];
Dimensions[x] (* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} *)
x = Transpose[x, {2, 1, 5, 3, 4}];
Dimensions[x] (* {2, 1, 4, 5, 3} *)
```

i.e. level `k` goes to level `{2, 1, 5, 3, 4}[[k]]`.

In Torch instead (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.permute.html) I get the following:

```python
x = torch.zeros((1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
x.shape  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
x = torch.permute(x, (1, 0, 4, 2, 3))  # {2, 1, 5, 3, 4} with 0-based indexing
x.shape  # [2, 1, 5, 3, 4] != {2, 1, 4, 5, 3}
```

that is, the argument to `torch.permute()` defines the desired ordering of the resulting dimensions.

This agrees with NumPy's `numpy.tranpose()` (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html)

```python
x = numpy.zeros((1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
x.shape  # (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
x = numpy.transpose(x, (1, 0, 4, 2, 3))
x.shape  # (2, 1, 5, 3, 4) != {2, 1, 4, 5, 3}
```

Is there an equivalent Mathematica function replicate this NumPy/Torch functionality?

Comment: Looks right to me.  `{2, 1, 5, 3, 4}` says level 3 should go to level 5 and in general, level `k` should go to level `{2, 1, 5, 3, 4}[[k]]`.

Comment: I see, I should have read the documentation more carefully....
I had this in mind:
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.permute.html
(bear in mind the 0-indexing).
Is there a function provided by Mathematica that corresponds to the above?

Comment: `x = torch.zeros((1, 2, 3, 4, 5)); x.shape  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; x = torch.permute(x, (1, 0, 4, 2, 3))  # 0-indexing; x.shape  # [2, 1, 5, 3, 4]`

Comment: As far as I can tell, Transpose is the analogous function, you just need to use 1-based indexing instead of 0-bases. If I'm not understanding, then please provide a test case (i.e. a reasonably sized array and the expected output).

Comment: I see you added a comment, and maybe that's supposed to be a test case, but I don't understand it.

Comment: Let me edit the question to make it clearer, I can't get multi-line formatting to work in comments...

Comment: Also, the title of this question is misleading. The answer to "is it a bug" is no--that issue is resolved. You should update your question to be in line with what you're now asking for.

Comment: Done, took me a while to edit, apologies. Not a bug indeed, just my missunderstanding.

Comment: yeah, that still doesn't help me. I'm not going to research torch, and I'm not going to make assumptions about how shape, zeros, and permute work. Give us an array in Mathematica that will be your input, and another array in Mathematica that you want as output, and we can show you how to make that happen.

Comment: it is clarified in the NumPy's documentation: The `i`’th axis of the returned array will correspond to the axis numbered `axes[i]` of the input, where I called `numpy.transpose(x, axes)`.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: `Ordering[{2, 1, 5, 3, 4}]` gives `{2, 1, 4, 5, 3}`. So, you could try `Transpose[x, Ordering[{2, 1, 5, 3, 4}]]` or something along those lines.

Comment: That is perfect :) If you can add this as a reply I'll accept it, thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: From the docs of `Transpose`: "Transpose[a,perm] returns an array of dimensions Permute[Dimensions[a],perm]". Representing a permutation by the ordered image of `Range[n]` seems pretty normal to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Transpose[x, Ordering[{2, 1, 5, 3, 4}]]
```

The key here is that Transpose uses the word-representation of the permutation.

Comment: Do you think you could expand on "Transpose uses the word-representation of the permutation"? I found that explanation quite opaque.

Comment: It's just jargon, and I'm not sure of the origin. I actually wanted to contrast it with whatever the representation used by torch is called, but I don't know what that representation is called.

Comment: Mathematica's usage here is what I assumed was standard representation for a permutation "function".  But this post made me think that I shouldn't consider it standard, and so I wanted to give it a name. Having finally taken some time to read a bit of the linked documentation, I think that the word "permutation" was just being used differently. I was thinking of "permutation" as a function-ish/group-ish thing, but torch and numpy are using it to mean the result you get after applying such a function/group thing

Comment: I'm guessing that Mathematica's Transpose is, therefore, much more general and powerful. For example, note that Mathematica's Transpose allows you to specify permutation cycles. But that's a guess becuase I didn't dig very deep into torch or numpy.

Answer (score 4):

```
Flatten[x, List /@ {2, 1, 5, 3, 4}];
```